# How to Pass the Data from one page to another page through URL Parameter

Tags: php

IN the PHP File the Brand value is Showing but when I trying to get it through another page it return NULL.

**Page1**
**PHP**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="row vertical-divider-page3">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="page3-img">
<img src="<?php echo $value["Image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive"  id="custompage">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="page4">
<a href="product.php?post=Reference&value=$value"> <h3 id="custompage"><?php echo $value["Brand"]; ?><span><br><?php echo $value["Reference"]; ?></span></h3></a> 
</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Product Page**

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when i try to get the Brand value on Another page through URL it return  Undefined index Brand. My code on another page is <?php echo $_GET["Brand"]; ?>

Comment: @Alisahibzada: And where do you try to pass any value called `Brand` to another page?  The code you're showing doesn't seem to demonstrate the problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: @David but in the URL i am trying to pass $value which is an array and contain all the detail. on the another page when i try to get the value like <?php echo $_GET["Brand"]; ?> it return Null

Comment: @Alisahibzada: You're passing URL values called `post` and `value`, you're not passing anything called `Brand`.  Do you mean to use `$_GET["value"]` on that other page?

Comment: Yes i mean $_GET["Brand"] but it return null. I want to get the Brand Value on another page through url.

Comment: @Alisahibzada Please extract all commented information and edit your question.  It is not nice for future SO readers to have to comb the collapsible comment section to get the full story.  Your question will have the potential to help others and gain upvotes if you can write a clear, concise, complete question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to pass $value into your url which won't work for two reasons.

1. You didn't echo this value in PHP so you're literally just passing the string `$value`.  Looks like you're trying to pass the 'Brand' along so you'll need to make sure your url query parameter is 'Brand=$value["Brand"]' and not just $value.
2. $value is an array and you cannot pass an array into the url like you are trying to do.

`<a href="product.php?post=Reference&Brand=<?php echo $value["Brand"]; ?>"> <h3 id="custompage"><?php echo $value["Brand"]; ?><span><br><?php echo $value["Reference"]; ?></span></h3></a>`

Comment: I have chane it to <a href="product.php?post=Reference&Brand=<?php echo $value["Brand"]; ?>">  But when i trying to get it into another page through $_GET["Brand"] it return NULL.

Comment: on product.php $_GET['Brand'] is NULL when you click that link?  Is $value['Brand'] set on page1?  Does the link text work properly?  Maybe it needs to be urlencoded:  echo urlencode($value['Brand'])

Comment: but it return Null. on the another page.